# Passing props in React jsx as generics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, jsx

In my react app i want to pass a specific interface as a generic into a unspecific component.

For example i have three specific interfaces

```
SpecificInterfaces.jsx
export interface InterfaceA {
   name: string
   age: number
   ...
}

export interface InterfaceB {
    name: string
    movies: string[]
    count: number
    ...
}

export interface InterfaceC {
    name: string
    somestuff: someType
}
```

For each of the interfaces i have a specific component ComponentA, ComponentB and ComponentC.
These Components need to be used in a shared component ComponentShared.

Now for example i want in my ComponentA to return SharedComponent with the generic Type of InterfaceA and props of Type InterfaceA like this:

```
ComponentA.jsx
export interface Props<T> {
    importData: T[]
    ... some props... 
}

const props: Props<InterfaceA> = {
importData: importData //This is from Interface Type InterfaceA
... someProps ...
}
  return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <SharedComponent<InterfaceA> {...props} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

And in my sharedComponent i want to access the specific passed generic type like this:

```
SharedComponent.jsx
const SharedComponent= <T,>({
   importData,
   ...the passed Props
}: Props<T>): JSX.Element => {
importData.map((data: T) =>
    data.name)
```

At `importData.map((data:T) => data.name)` it throws an error, saying T has no member of name. So i guess something isnt working with my generics i pass in here, because the InterfaceA im passing in as generic has the member "name" like any ohter InterfaceB and InterfaceC. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know anything about the generic inside your function unless you inform it. You need to extend your generic `T` from a type that has the properties that you use inside the function. Consider this example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgcwHIEMC2BTAZwCEAnOAazyQB4AVAPgAo4AjAKz2gIC5FaBtALoBKXgDc4MACaIA3gFgAUIkTA4JRIwgICURKzb7g+9pygFhcpSpXawBOMjwA6VGmbtnYXHmEBuJQB6ACobMPCIgD1oyKUABTIABzwSKABPRAByb3xMxCk4QkQwOD08AA8YXX0kdOSs2kznRgAmAGY2gE5LYMDrRABfJSHFJTq8RCIsAjwAeVNoRABeK2Vin15dEhgwNADFAf2lUEhYBBR0bHwCRDpECqgqKRupmfmOaCYDMx4+IVFEBJpKsVGoNFodHoDEYTB9zJYFGtbDpHC43B42F4fP5EIFAvpyMU4AB3fojEZAA)

```ts
function logNamesBroken <T>(objects: T[]): void {
  for (const obj of objects) {
    console.log(obj.name);
/*                  ^^^^
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'T'.(2339) */
  }
}

type BaseObject = {
  name: string;
};

function logNames <T extends BaseObject>(objects: T[]): void {
  for (const obj of objects) {
    console.log(obj.name); // ok now
  }
}
```

---

More, based on the code in your question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAWAChfgAdjBRRM5FHABChFAElhjBLzhwBGECgBccAjCiCA5tx5Ve-ISLETZF0RRQBBOCgAewgUiLSCchYmVwGAZaqlggAEYixqZ8PILCduJwAAr0YAQAPAAqzm4oHl4y8iggAHz+PCqgkLAAIhgwGNpZANoAutFmPOQQArpwAMoAFhisSADCDJAC+fAAvHDZue6eUkUKpQAUSpVw1dAw9Y0ANLxU2qkQ6dmlAJTapBQwAHSPlACiOCWzcHPlOypWDAsFABHBNgEVBlcKVISoKvDEXtwAcjhhniAMGBNpskA0MMc9h5XLdfuUIbskfCMjhgHAANYoACecwQAAMACQIQSoFxUAC0XLxjWeag0VDZVFKyHxovUKCoGQA9LTYZSkbdbnCVDFEcqYQFbtFjLwen14Ps6vjtDYElYHO1fnAWggxSEmBgmISgiEAIxUQmu+XaJjhL2BYLaABMVA6XTN-TAaQIF2TGVtlnsDnKCwByJqh3xpxMJu6vX6DgEEBgQxEkxRMyETs29xIbBebxgn2+Tb+4ICGU7zwAYlAghohGq9cNRigJlNej8EM8V0mrgQaEqp4slUPR+PZmqjUA)

```ts
import {default as React} from 'react';

interface BaseItem {
  name: string;
}

interface InterfaceA extends BaseItem {
  age: number;
}

interface Props<T extends BaseItem> {
  importData: T[];
}

const SharedComponent = <T extends BaseItem>({
  importData,
}: Props<T>): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        importData.map((data, index) => (
          <li key={`${index}-${data.name}`}>{data.name}</li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  );
};

const importData: InterfaceA[] = [{name: 'a', age: 1}, {name: 'b', age: 2}];

const props: Props<InterfaceA> = {
  importData,
};

const AnotherComponent = (): React.ReactElement => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <SharedComponent {...props} />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
Do I understand it correctly, then what I want to achieve is not possible like that at all? Because I have several interfaces or types, which should be compatible with the SharedComponent. These interfaces or types are to be extended in the near future also and/or supplemented by new types...

Comment: @Alex To be honest, it's difficult for me to understand the code in your question because it's not valid syntax: there are un-commented comments mixed in with code, `return` statements outside functions, etc. It's hard for me to make out what your intention really is, however, I updated my answer with another example based on what I gathered.

Comment: Your new solution seems to do what i wanted! I need to verify it a bit but it looks great so far. Thank you so much! 
Yeah i know, honestly im not really sure what im supposed to do exactly i just got the task "make the component work with generics"... :D